# Is it possible to modify or mock the Inversify container used by a Typescript class in a Jasmine unit test?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, inversifyjs

I have a Typescript class that uses InversifyJS and [Inversify Inject Decorators](https://github.com/inversify/inversify-inject-decorators) to inject a service into a private property. Functionally this is fine but I'm having issues figuring out how to unit test it. I've created a simplified version of my problem below.

In the Jasmine unit test, how can I swap out the injected `RealDataService` with a `FakeDataService`? If the property wasn't private I could create the component and assign a fake service but I am wondering if this is possible by using the IOC Container.

I initially followed this [this example in the InversifyJS recipes page](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/recipes.md#overriding-bindings-on-unit-tests) but quickly realised that the container they created isn't used in any class under test. Also, most of the code examples that I can see in the [InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) docs don't cover how to unit test it.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

**myComponent.ts**

```
import { lazyInject, Types } from "./ioc";
import { IDataService } from "./dataService";

export default class MyComponent {

    @lazyInject(Types.IDataService)
    private myDataService!: IDataService;

    getSomething(): string {
        return this.myDataService.get();
    }
}
```

**dataService.ts**

```
import { injectable } from "inversify";

export interface IDataService {
    get(): string;
}

@injectable()
export class RealDataService implements IDataService {
    get(): string {
        return "I am real!";
    }
}
```

**IOC Configuration**

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Container, ContainerModule, interfaces, BindingScopeEnum } from "inversify";
import getDecorators from "inversify-inject-decorators";

import { IDataService, RealDataService } from "./dataService";

const Types = {
    IDataService: Symbol.for("IDataService")
};

const iocContainerModule = new ContainerModule((bind: interfaces.Bind) => {
    bind<IDataService>(Types.IDataService).to(RealDataService);
});

const iocContainer = new Container();
iocContainer.load(iocContainerModule);
const { lazyInject } = getDecorators(iocContainer);
export { lazyInject, Types };
```

**Unit Tests**

```
import { Container } from "inversify";
import { Types } from "./ioc";
import MyComponent from "./myComponent";
import { IDataService } from "./dataService";

class FakeDataService implements IDataService {
    get(): string {
        return "I am fake!";
    }
}

describe("My Component", () => {
    let iocContainer!: Container;
    let myComponent!: MyComponent;

    beforeEach(() => {
        iocContainer = new Container();
        iocContainer.bind(Types.IDataService).to(FakeDataService);

        // How do I make myComponent use this iocContainer?
        // Is it even possible?

        myComponent = new MyComponent();
    });

    it("should use the mocked service", () => {
        const val = myComponent.getSomething();
        expect(val).toBe("I am fake!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this by importing a container from a different file. Using this method, you would write a different container for every combination of dependencies you want to inject into a test. For brevity, assume the code example with ninja warriors given by the Inversify docs.

```js
// src/inversify.prod-config.ts
import "reflect-metadata";
import { Container } from "inversify";
import { TYPES } from "./types";
import { Warrior, Weapon, ThrowableWeapon } from "./interfaces";
import { Ninja, Katana, Shuriken } from "./entities";

const myContainer = new Container();
myContainer.bind<Warrior>(TYPES.Warrior).to(Ninja);
myContainer.bind<Weapon>(TYPES.Weapon).to(Katana);
myContainer.bind<ThrowableWeapon>(TYPES.ThrowableWeapon).to(Shuriken);

export { myContainer };
```

```js
// test/fixtures/inversify.unit-config.ts
import "reflect-metadata";
import {Container, inject, injectable} from "inversify";
import { TYPES } from "../../src/types";
import { Warrior, Weapon, ThrowableWeapon } from "../../src/interfaces";

// instead of importing the injectable classes from src,
// import mocked injectables from a set of text fixtures.
// For brevity, I defined mocks inline here, but you would
// likely want these in their own files.

@injectable()
class TestKatana implements Weapon {
  public hit() {
    return "TEST cut!";
  }
}

@injectable()
class TestShuriken implements ThrowableWeapon {
  public throw() {
    return "TEST hit!";
  }
}

@injectable()
class TestNinja implements Warrior {

  private _katana: Weapon;
  private _shuriken: ThrowableWeapon;

  public constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.Weapon) katana: Weapon,
    @inject(TYPES.ThrowableWeapon) shuriken: ThrowableWeapon
  ) {
    this._katana = katana;
    this._shuriken = shuriken;
  }

  public fight() { return this._katana.hit(); }
  public sneak() { return this._shuriken.throw(); }

}

const myContainer = new Container();
myContainer.bind<Warrior>(TYPES.Warrior).to(TestNinja);
myContainer.bind<Weapon>(TYPES.Weapon).to(TestKatana);
myContainer.bind<ThrowableWeapon>(TYPES.ThrowableWeapon).to(TestShuriken);

export { myContainer };
```

```js
// test/unit/example.test.ts
// Disclaimer: this is a Jest test, but a port to jasmine should look similar.

import {myContainer} from "../fixtures/inversify.unit-config";
import {Warrior} from "../../../src/interfaces";
import {TYPES} from "../../../src/types";

describe('test', () => {
  let ninja;

  beforeEach(() => {
    ninja = myContainer.get<Warrior>(TYPES.Warrior);
  });

  test('should pass', () => {
    expect(ninja.fight()).toEqual("TEST cut!");
    expect(ninja.sneak()).toEqual("TEST hit!");
  });
});
```

Comment: You could also just define the container inside the same test file, so that you can have unique mock objects per test suite.

Comment: I think the question was about @lazyInject, which is tied to a particular container instance, so you can't switch it with another one in the test. I guess the only way to deal with it is to move loading of container modules to a separate function, which would run only in production, while using a separate configuring function of the same container instance for the tests.

Answer (score 2):

Try exporting the container from your IOC configuration, `ioc.ts`, like this
`export { iocContainer, lazyInject, Types };`

Then you can rebind the `IDataService` Symbol to your mocked `FakeDataService` in the unit test

```
    import { Types, iocContainer } from "../tmp/ioc";
    import MyComponent from "../tmp/myComponent";
    import { IDataService } from "../tmp/dataService";
    import { injectable } from "inversify";

    @injectable() // Added
    class FakeDataService implements IDataService {
        get(): string {
            return "I am fake!";
        }
    }

    describe("My Component", () => {
        let myComponent!: MyComponent;

        beforeAll(() => {
            // Rebind the service
            iocContainer.rebind<IDataService>(Types.IDataService).to(FakeDataService);

            // Alternatively you could do it like this with the same end result:
            iocContainer.unbind(Types.IDataService);
            iocContainer.bind<IDataService>(Types.IDataService).to(FakeDataService);

            myComponent = new MyComponent();
        });

        it("should use the mocked service", () => {
            const val = myComponent.getSomething();
            expect(val).toBe("I am fake!");
        });
    });
```

I tried it myself and it works fine. [I found this via the inversify.js container API docs](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/container_api.md)